# Remember wifi password but never automatically connect

Tags: wi-fi

I have both my wifi password and my friend's saved.  Since they live nearby sometimes it will automatically switch to theirs if the signal is stronger.  I don't ordinarily want to use their connection unless I'm over there or my internet is down.

Is here any way to make android only automatically connect to my wifi without forgetting the other's password? It is long and impossible to memorize so forgetting the network is a huge pain.

Running ICS, and have root if needed.

Comment: Does toggling "Avoid poor connections" in `Settings > Wi-Fi > Advanced` change this behavior?

Comment: Sounds promising but unable to find such an option.  The device is an asus transformer prime running android 4.0.3

Comment: Might not be available in the stock Asus ROM. Bummer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly what you may have intended, but still a possible solution: Using an app like

- [Wifi QR Code Generator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madeng.wifiqr)
- [WiFi QR Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sudomakemeanapp.wifiqr)

you can generate a QR Code of your friend's Wifi connection, print it, laminate it (for protection), and put it into your wallet. Now, whenever you want to use that Wifi network, take out the QR-Code, scan it with [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) -- and get connected. For a "log-out" simply disconnect, and *remove* the network from your list (to keep your device from autoconnecting).

Not quite elegant -- but it saves you from typing the long password everytime. Side-Effect: Print out the QR multiple times, and give it to your friend's for other guests. Do the same for your own Wifi. Now you never have to tell your passwords: To permit your guests to connect, somply show them the QR-Code to scan (and have them delete the network from their devices when they leave, as Android stores Wifi-passwords unencrypted).

Comment: " have them delete the network from their devices"  Why would you do that?

Comment: Because "Android stores Wifi-passwords unencrypted"? It's just a security question. Maybe I should add "optionally". But as the OP doesn't want to automatically connect to the friend's network, maybe the visitors don't want that, either.

Comment: Definitely not as elegant as I would like...but I suppose it's a step above what I have now.

Comment: I was aware of that -- but I'm afraid the real elegant solution won't be available. At least I know of no setting to tell Android not to connect a specific network automatically, once you have it in your list of "known networks" (i.e. once you connected to it and did not remove it afterwards).

Comment: +1, although I find it a bit sad that in 2019, the best solution still seems to be carrying a booklet of printed QR codes around with your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, as said before I am afraid that there is no such setting available. BUT there is a handy little app that lets you create widgets that let you switch your networks with a single tap. So when you realize you are connected to your friend's network, simply press the button on your homescreen and you will be connected to your own network again.

You can find the app here: [Wifi Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kman.WifiManager).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to your **wpa_supplicant** file and changing the priority on the networks?
The settings will be save in regular text and they'll easy to read and figure out.

If you have a [Root explorer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root%20explorer&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiDwoNcm9vdCBleHBsb3JlcnoCGACKAQIIAQ%3D%3D%3AS%3AANO1ljIucBM&hl=en) like ES file or any other you can find it by looking here → `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Note : *Also there are some apps that let you do this if you don't want to try and find the file yourself*