# connect to specific wifi only

Tags: wi-fi, security

I want my device to be connected to a certain wifi network only. Lets assume  WiFi named "xyz": so my device should connect to this particular "xyz" network only. It Should not connect to any other network.

More precisely: I don't want other user's to use my device with any other WiFi network. Basically I want to restrict user to access other network.

My device is rooted, so can I achieve this by doing some settings at OS level?

Comment: You might want to check [Remember wifi password but never automatically connect](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27499/16575) and [Disable a specific WiFi network from automatically connecting to in Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35332/16575). Furthermore, Android won't connect you to any WiFi network automatically until you at least once connected to it manually (i.e. it's stored in your list of "known networks", where you can remove it from anytime).

Comment: @Izzy hey thanks for reply, But it is not much useful for me. There is not any other way to achieve this, like by modifying wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: I don't know of such. But as said: as long as you do not manually connect to a network, Android won't automatically connect to it. So if you want your device to connect to "xyz" only, do not connect it to any other network manually.

Comment: @Izzy actually i don't want other user's to use my device with any other wifi network. Basically i want to restrict user to access other network. so can u tell me is there any setting or any app which can help me to provide security. Thank you! :)

Comment: Ah! *That* part was missing in your original question. I've added it to make it clear (just in the comments, it would be lost). AFAIK there's no such "OS setting" (and if there was, "other users" could manipulate it as well). You might look in the Playstore for [app lockers](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app+lock&c=apps), they should be able to "lock" the settings app as well. De-Activate the "inform me about open WiFi networks" to avoid the popup, and together with an app locker that should do what you're looking for.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for such quick response. I will try with 'app locking' application. But in case if u gt any other solution please let me know.

Comment: Not me alone :) Please don't forget to report back whether the app lockers solved you issue, so I might setup a more complete answer with this solution.

Comment: @Izzy i am using [This security app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree&feature=search_result) Thanks for giving hint. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no such "OS setting" (and if there was, "other users" could manipulate it as well).

As a "work-around", you might look in the Playstore for app lockers, they should be able to "lock" the settings app as well. Remove all WiFi APNs from your network list which should not be connected, de-Activate the "inform me about open WiFi networks" to avoid the popup, and together with an app locker (locking the "settings" app) that should do what you're looking for.

As to your comment, this seems to work fine with [Smart AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree), which can lock not only apps but also some system actions:

[image: Smart AppLock: Lock apps] [image: Smart AppLock: System locks]
<sup>Smart AppLock: Locking apps, locking system actions (source: Google Play; click images for larger variant)</sup>