# Prevent phone auto-connect to a specific wifi connection, without forgetting that connection

Tags: wi-fi, 9.0-pie

The feature I am looking for exist on MIUI rom and samsung roms:

[image]

Similar question were asked before: 
[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131116/how-to-prevent-wifi-auto-connect-without-forgetting-that-connection) from 2015 has an answer about Samsung and MIUI roms only.

Answers to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35332/disable-a-specific-wifi-network-from-automatically-connecting-to-in-android) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27499/remember-wifi-password-but-never-automatically-connect) question  (both from 2013) offer workarounds.

An answer to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/how-can-i-tell-my-device-to-ignore-a-public-wi-fi-network) question suggested to use [Wi-fi Ruller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hogdex.WifiRuler) which unfortunately is not supported anymore.

It looks like the questions are rather old, and a simple, straight forward direct solution is yet to be found.

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: Because it looks like the ROM must implement it or you must be rooted

Comment: @colbycdev  Yes, I  am rooted.  I would have used MIUI rom but there is no version for the phone I use.

Comment: it looks like an OEM implementation. So it must be implemented in the ROM.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, there really is no way to do it directly

There are root workaround but nothing that only allows manual connection (excluding Samsung or MIUI stuff); it must be OEM implemented. I can't find any way to do it in standard AOSP or lineage OS

You could always try something like Tasker and have it shut off WiFi when your in range of a network you don't want to automatically connect to

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think it would be quiet complicated with automation. The need is not to turn wifi on and off, but rather remembering a  connection without auto connecting to it. It seems silly to me that I need to forget a connection and key the password again, just because I don't want to connect to it evey time it is in range. Connection prioritizing makes sense but it is also too cumbersome.

Comment: @c0der sadly it has to be implemented ROM side. There is no easy way to do it otherwise. And only Samsung and xiaomi have it